# How to set position of subplot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I try to set this subplot one after another, But cannot change their position. What can i do?

```
figure
subplot(10,1,1,'Position',[0.5,0.69,1,0.1]);plot(B{1, 1}(:,[1,3]),'Color', 
[0,0,0]);legend('Black');
subplot(10,1,2,'Position',[0.5,0.37,1,0.1]);plot(B{2, 1}(:,[1,3]),'Color', 
[1,0,0]);legend('Red');
subplot(10,1,3,'Position',[0,0,1,0.1]);plot(B{3, 1}(:,[1,3]),'Color', 
[0,1,0]);legend('Lime');
subplot(10,1,4,'Position',[0,0,1,0.1]);plot(B{4, 1}(:,[1,3]),'Color', 
[0,0,1]);legend('Blue');
subplot(10,1,5,'Position',[0,0,1,0.1]);plot(B{5, 1}(:,[1,3]),'Color', 
[0,1,1]);legend('Cyan');
subplot(10,1,6,'Position',[0,0,1,0.1]);plot(B{6, 1}(:,[1,3]),'Color', 
[1,0,1]);legend('Magenta');
subplot(10,1,7,'Position',[0,0,1,0.1]);plot(B{7, 1}(:,[1,3]),'Color', 
[0.5,0.5,0.5]);legend('Gray');
subplot(10,1,8,'Position',[0,0,1,0.1]);plot(B{8, 1}(:,[1,3]),'Color', 
[0.5,0,0]);legend('Maroon');
subplot(10,1,9,'Position',[0,0,1,0.1]);plot(B{9, 1}(:,[1,3]),'Color', 
[0.5,0,0.5]);legend('Purple');
subplot(10,1,10,'Position',[0,0,1,0.1]);plot(B{10, 1}(:,[1,3]),'Color', 
[0,0.5,0.5]);legend('Teal');
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can change the position, as long as you do it properly.

As stated in the [manual of the subplot](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html), you can specify the position:

- Automatically

by using

```
subplot(m,n,p)
```

Which uses the `m` *x* `n` grid plotting in the `p` position. This is what you partially used.

- Manually

by using

```
subplot('Position',[left bottom width height])
```

And this is where you have a problem. As it states in the manual, if it overlap, it will erase the graph that is under.
In your case, several of the positions are overlapping.
Note also that the positions are always normalized, so  `left=0.5` with a `width=1` means that you cropped half of the figure in the x direction. Pay attention when you use manual positioning.
As [Cris Luengo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50929148/2107764) pointed out, you can use `axis` directly. Which has a few pros and cons. However the unit in `axis` are also normalized. So, know what you are using.

When you use both (manual and automatic) settings, it is not clear to me which one will have preferences, as i got different outputs when i tested a part of your code.

Comment: Good point about the coordinates OP uses. 8 of the axes get the same location, that cannot be right.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to set their position by hand, just create the axes objects directly:

```
figure
axes('Position',[0.5,0.69,1,0.1]);plot(B{1, 1}(:,[1,3]),'Color', 
[0,0,0]);legend('Black');
axes('Position',[0.5,0.37,1,0.1]);plot(B{2, 1}(:,[1,3]),'Color', 
[1,0,0]);legend('Red');
```

[Documentation to `axes`.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html)

The nice thing about `subplot` is that it places the axes for you. It has no other purpose.