# Subplot priority in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I was replying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928826/how-to-set-position-of-subplot-in-matlab) question and i came with a problem -- kind of, It is more like a curiosity.

*Who has the priority in Matlab subplot, the automatic plot or the position property and why?*

I tried a few tests and i got some weird results as the images below,

[image: Babou][image: Babou][image: Babou]

[Auto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogi0k.png), [Manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IyAO.png), [Both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAQ5G.png).

This is the code used.

```
a=1:10;b=a.^2;
figure
subplot('Position',[0.3,0.7,0.5,0.1]);plot(a,b,'-k');legend('Black');
subplot('Position',[0.3,0.3,0.5,0.1]);plot(a,b,'-r');legend('Red');
figure
subplot(2,1,1);plot(a,b,'-k');legend('Black');
subplot(2,1,2);plot(a,b,'-r');legend('Red');
figure
subplot(2,1,1,'Position',[0.3,0.7,0.5,0.1]);plot(a,b,'-k');legend('Black');
subplot(2,1,2,'Position',[0.3,0.3,0.5,0.1]);plot(a,b,'-r');legend('Red');
```

As you can see, the last image plot is messy, generating a axis in the proper position, but using the

Using 3 plots and the same scheme as before (with smaller changes in positions numbers), the last one has the following output:
[image: both 3 plots]

Which is not much better. For the 'one plot only' case, it follows the manual `Position` settings.

I found this note in the [manual](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)

> When using a script to create subplots, MATLAB does not finalize the Position property value until either a drawnow command is issued or MATLAB returns to await a user command. The Position property value for a subplot is subject to change until the script either refreshes the plot or exits.

With this i got an idea about the problem. The position is called when it draw the second graph only, but then it writes over the first position call, leaving the second axis empty. Following this, in the one with 3 plots, it should then write the last call `green` over the second graph or first one, but it goes to the last one, as one desire initially.

As an extra comment, this is the behavior in the 2017a version. 2016a(from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50939237/2107764) ) works fine. 2018a works fine, but generates a warning about the double entry.

Any idea how Matlab uses the subplot scheme that define this multiple subplots  and what exactly is the reason to have this outputs (exemplified in this case by clearly incompatible instructions)?

Answer (score 1):

I just re-ran your script in Matlab 2016a and I don't have this problem and matlab does what I expect. If you don't define a position it uses the default settings, if you define one, it uses the position you use. Usually the properties that you set manually always get priority because you explicitly define/call them. (Why I don't know, but to me it seems like logical thinking, do what I tell you and if I don't tell you make a good guess/assumption)

Also Matlab, defines the positions of the axes (of the subplots). It does not keep track of where the subplots are in the series of subplots after having plotted them. You can see this if you save the handles. The only thing saved is the final position of the axes of each subplot. The column and row numbers are not saved in the handles of the subplots (maybe in the parent figure/axes but I would have to check).

So this is probably a version dependent issue, my results:
[image]

Comment: Indeed, this should be the case, and it is for the 2018a version as well. I will test in a 2014 version just for curiosity to see the behavior.